# Notifications are not working in Android Oreo

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap, pushwoosh, android-8.0-oreo

I am using pushwoosh plugin for pushnotification in my cordova phonegap application.
Actually the issue is that notifications are not coming in the Android O devices.

Cordova Android Platform is :: 4.1.1
Pushwoosh Plugin version :: 6.3.0

can you please help me out to solve this issue.

Android 8 is using Notification channel, so how to implement channel code in pushwoosh.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cordova Firebase Plugin. Its very simple to use. If you want to use this plugin visit https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

And check this video for tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvRGNrGpI_A

Comment: I can't change from pushwoosh to firebase for push notification as if now.
So have to work with push woosh for notification.